# R count variable in Vector by split/Group?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, count

I have the following Dataset (not the real Dataset)
The Dataframe has lots of players (player2, player3 etc) and Dates and reported status.  I am trying to summarize the Number of Fails in each date for each player.

```
Players <- rep("player1", 24)
Date <- c(rep("2020-10-22", 6), rep("2020-10-21", 8), rep("2020-10-18",10))
status <- c("Enter", "start", "stop", "start" , "stop", "Exit",
            "Enter", "start", "start_fail", "start", "stop", "start", "stop", "Exit",
            "Enter", "Enter_Fail", "start", "stop", "start", 
            "injured", "start_fail", "start", "stop", "Exit")
df <- data.frame(Players = Players, Date = Date, status= status)
x = c("Enter_fail", "start_fail")
```

I grouped the Data by `group_by` and did the `count`

```
df %>% group_by(Players, Date) %>% summarise(fail_count = sum(status %in% x)
```

But the problem is, if the status "injured" is read, the corresponding start_fail is not counted as failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% mutate(fail_count = case_when(lag(status) != 'injured' &  grepl('[Ff]ail$',status) == TRUE ~ 1,
+                                          status == 'injured' &  grepl('[Ff]ail$',status) == TRUE ~ 0,
+                                           TRUE ~ 0)) %>% filter(fail_count == 1) %>% 
+                                         group_by(Players, Date) %>% 
+                                         summarise(fail_count = sum(fail_count))
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'Players' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   Players [1]
  Players Date       fail_count
  <chr>   <date>          <dbl>
1 player1 2020-10-18          1
2 player1 2020-10-21          1
>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The count works, but what i am trying is, in the Date 2020-10-18 , the actual fail_count is 1 , because, the second failure happened because of injury hence is not counted in fail_count. Basically, whenever Injured is read in the column, next 'Fail' is not counted

Comment: @SriRam, have made changes to my code, please check if it works for you now.